# How to find or clear traces of deleted folders in windows 11?

Tags: windows-registry, windows-11, cleaning

I'd like to understand specifically how and where does this program finds traces of my deleted folders, do any of you have any idea how to find or clear them manually?

To be more specific, those folders were permanently removed from my computer, yet this program finds traces of them somehow and I want to understand how, thank you very much.

[image: Program screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The program just scans Windows registry, finds directories in keys/values and then checks if they exist. If it can't detect them, it reports them as "removed". It doesn't know what happened to them exactly and if they were e.g. moved or renamed.

Using programs like that **isn't** what I'd recommend doing, especially to less technical users. They can yield positive results at times, but if you're not careful enough, you might remove some kind of important registry entry that might heavily damage your system.

And the advantages are almost irrelevant. If it's e.g. a leftover from an application that was removed, most of them don't do anything wrong to your system, except just taking a little disk space. Some of them like invalid autorun or context menu entries might be worth removing, but it's better done manually, with careful verification. These areas often have their own dedicated cleanup programs, like [Autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) for autorun apps.

Also, to avoid more and more leftovers appearing, you could learn to use [BCUninstaller](https://github.com/Klocman/Bulk-Crap-Uninstaller) that scans for remaining files/registry after uninstalling programs. It's not perfect either, nothing automated will be, considering Windows registry isn't too strict and can be a mess, but it's usually quite accurate and has probability rating.

See also this old yet still relevant [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/registry-junk-a-windows-fact-of-life/ba-p/723422).

Comment: read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry for more info